# input tag text loaded with sammy.js and can't write into

Tags: javascript, html

Using Sammy.js for a single page appliaction:

```
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="  אימייל" class="email-input">
```

the thing is I can't type text into it!
I pretty sure it's due to loading it with `sammy.js`

```
 this.get('#/', function() {
                    $("#main-block").load("templates/first-page.html.erb", function() {
                        Global.init();
                    });
}
```

example here:

http://ohadpartuck.github.io/side-projects/#/

Answer (score 0):

turns out the issue was with this js code:

```
 $('#notify-form').bind('keypress', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if(code == 13) { //'Enter' keycode
                    Global.formSubmit();
                }
            });
```

once I removed it the problem resolved...